# Prisma upsert and delete old relations

Tags: typescript, orm, prisma

I have a project that is composed on `Posts` and each post can have a collection of `Tags`. I'm trying to enable an edit feature that allows Post tags to be updates / added / removed. Currently, my query upserts these tags, but I'm experiencing some trouble caused by the deletion aspect. Any time new tags are created, since they have no ID at the time, they are deleted immediately.

```
await Prisma.post.update({
            where: {
                id: postId,
            },
            data: {
                title,
                content,
                updatedAt: new Date(),
                tags: {
                    // Upsert tags, remove tags that are not in the request
                    upsert: tags.map((tag) => ({
                        where: {
                            id: tag.id ? tag.id : "0",
                        },
                        create: {
                            name: tag.name,
                            color: tag.color,
                            creator: {
                                connect: {
                                    id: session.user.id,
                                },
                            },
                        },
                        update: {
                            name: tag.name,
                            color: tag.color,
                        },
                    })),
                    deleteMany: {
                        id: {
                            notIn: tags.map((tag) => tag.id ?? "0"),
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
            include: {
                tags: true,
            },
        });
```

I've attempted various solutions such as keying on the name or other properties (e.g. name AND color). None of these seem to fix the issue, as they end up duplicating tags and causing similar bugs.

Here are the schema I'm using my my Post and Tag models.

`Post`

```
model Post {
    id        String    @id @default(uuid())
    createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime  @updatedAt
    deletedAt DateTime?

    title    String
    content  String
    authorId String
    author   User      @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
    comments Comment[]
    tags     Tag[]
}
```

`Tag`

```
model Tag {
    id        String   @id @default(uuid())
    createdAt DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

    name      String
    color     String
    creatorId String
    creator   User   @relation(fields: [creatorId], references: [id])
    posts     Post[]
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction as to how one handles a situation like this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, could you share your post and tags schema please

Comment: @Pompedup Sure, I've gone ahead and updated the post with them. Also, if it's worth noting I am using Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cut out your steps in a transaction to delete the tags not in the query before inserting the new ones.
Then you can create and update your data and return your post

**With [interactiveTransactions](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/transactions#interactive-transactions-in-preview)**

In your `schema.prisma` you should enable `interactiveTransactions`, for this:

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["interactiveTransactions"]
}
```

Then cut out your steps in a transaction

```js
// Remove <Post> if you aren't in typescript
await prisma.$transaction<Post>(async (trx) => {
  const existingTags = tags.filter(({ id }) => id);
  const newTags = tags.filter(({ id }) => !id);

  await trx.tag.deleteMany({
    where: {
      id: {
        notIn: existingTags.map(({ id }) => id),
      },
    },
  });
  // Update the existing tags
  await Promise.all(
    tags.map((tag) =>
      trx.tag.update({
        where: {
          id: tag.id,
        },
        data: {
          color: tag.color,
          name: tag.name,
        },
      })
    )
  );
  await trx.tag.createMany({
    data: newTags.map((tag) => ({
      ...tag,
      creator: {
        connect: {
          id: session.user.id,
        },
      },
    })),
  });
  return trx.post.update({
    where: {
      id: postId,
    },
    data: {
      title,
      content,
      updatedAt: new Date(),
    },
    include: {
      tags: true,
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: This is super helpful, I didn't know about transactions beforehand. I was able to use these concepts to get the behavior I desired. In my case, I removed the delete, used `promise.all` to create and connect new tags (you cannot connect using createMany), and finally, I used `update` with `set` on the tags. Thanks a ton!